# Extract contract interface from a workflow service (WF 4.0)

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4

I have a workflow service created with WF 4.0 and the need to have a typical WCF decorated interface extracted from it, containing all operations. I need it for testing purposes.
Is there a way to extract a decorated interface from a workflow service?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If add a service reference from a non WF4 client application it will generate the normal client items including the service interface. Another way of doing the same is running SvcUtil against the service yourself. There is no service interface CS file in the service project itself, all of the required WCF artifacts are generated at runtime based on the XAMLX file instead.